# How to run Ruby on Android?

Tags: android, ruby

I installed a Ruby code editor (DroidEdit) I wrote a program but I don't know how I can test it on my Android device. How do I do that?

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: I have written a code for a component called DBC parser in ruby language, but not able to run on android device.

Comment: Root devise and install ruby with apt-get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the Ruby code using the app called [**Ruboto IRB**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ruboto.irb&hl=en) on Android devices. It needs Ruboto Core add-on download too. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Rhodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodes_Framework), Open source by Motorola.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Scripting Layer For Android](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ruby compiler via the web browser. http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: How to run a ruby code on a android device?

Comment: Yes, open that link with a browser on the androis.